# Alamofire put request

Tags: alamofire

Try to get Alamofire put request to work, but system shows "Extra Argument in Call"

```
Alamofire.request(.PUT, apiUrl,params,ParameterEncoding.JSON)
        .responseJOSN{ (request, response, products: [Product]?,error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(data)
            println(error)
    }
```

Anyone can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues in your code sample. Here's a corrected version that should get you going:

```
let apiURLString = "whatever/your/url/is"
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [:] // fill in your params

let request = Alamofire.request(.PUT, apiURLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
request.responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
    println(request)
    println(response)
    println(json)
    println(error)
}
```

I would also encourage you to really read through the Alamofire [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md) in depth. It has some great information and should make it much easier for you to get the basics working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cnoon, use the same code you provided, showing error "could not find member .PUT" AND "could not find member JSON". Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: I would guess you have a project setup issue. Did you remember to `import Alamofire`? How did you add Alamofire to your project? There are some great examples of how to add Alamofire to your project [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation).

Comment: The get request is working fine for me. Is that means the project setup alright? Would you have some sample project with put request.

Answer (score 0):

As   *'alamofire' '~2.0'* has changed the in number of parameters
You can try with the following block of code:

```
Alamofire.request(.PUT,apiUrl,params).responseJSON { request, response,  result in

print(request)
print(response)
print(result.value)

if(result.isSuccess){

 //Do in success block

 }else{
 //Do in failure block
 }
```

}

Alamofire.request does not have *error* handler parameter available, hence it was showing you that "Extra Argument in Call"